# Transaction Not happening Giving error Error E00040 Customer Profile ID or Customer Payment Profile ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorize.net

I am using the AuthorizeAndCapture method to initiate a transaction for a particular amount in sandbox environment.

below is the code used.

```
var customerGateWay =new CustomerGateway(_authorizeNetConfiguration, _loggerFactory);

var customerResponse = await customerGateWay.GetCustomerAsync(company.Company.ExternalCompanyProfileId);
//Getting response with profile id in customerResponse 
var response = customerGateWay.AuthorizeAndCapture(company.Company.ExternalCompanyProfileId, customerResponse.ProfileID, totalAmount);
//response is giving this error Error E00040 Customer Profile ID or Customer Payment Profile ID
```

Expected output is `transactionId` but giving this **Error E00040** Customer Profile ID or Customer Payment Profile ID

Comment: Looks like record cannot be found : https://www.neurochemistry.org/payment-error-codes/

Comment: yeah at the time of generating transaction but I am getting customer response detail with profileId so I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: You are getting a valid response back with an error in the response data.

Comment: should the transaction not occure shoulld it not responed as success as it's a sandbox account?

Comment: A response just indicates the server recognized the request was valid and can process the request.  If the customer doesn't exist then an error inside the response is allowable.

Comment: You should post the entire response contained in `customerResponse `